# Previous entry in list with key()-function

Tags: key, xslt-3.0

I've tried to simplify my problem ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58977093/how-to-access-previous-and-next-item-based-on-a-condition)) on how to access a previous entry in a list. Say i have a list like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <row>
        <letter>A</letter>
        <number>1</number>
    </row>
    <row>
        <letter>B</letter>
        <number>2</number>
    </row>
    <row>
        <letter>C</letter>
        <number>3</number>
    </row>
    <row>
        <letter>D</letter>
        <number>4</number>
    </row>
    <row>
        <letter>E</letter>
        <number>5</number>
    </row>
    <row>
        <letter>F</letter>
        <number>6</number>
    </row>
    <row>
        <letter>G</letter>
        <number>7</number>
    </row> 
    <row>
        <letter>H</letter>
        <number>8</number>
    </row>
</root>
```

And a simple XML-file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<base>
    <object>A</object>
   <object>B</object>
    <object>H</object>
</base>
```

I want to write the preceding entry next to every object. So this would be the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <group>
   <object>A</object>
   <preceding></preceding>
</group>
   <group>
   <object>B</object>
   <preceding>A</preceding>
</group>
    <group>
   <object>H</object>
   <preceding>G</preceding>
</group>
```

This is the XSL-code I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />
    <xsl:output indent="yes"
        method="xml"
        encoding="utf-8"
        omit-xml-declaration="false"/>

    <xsl:param name="alphabet" select="document('alphabet.xml')"/>
    <xsl:key name="letter-lookup" match="row" use="letter"/>

    <xsl:template match="base">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="object">
        <xsl:element name="group">
            <xsl:element name="object">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="preceding">
                <xsl:value-of select="key('letter-lookup', text(), $alphabet)/parent::*/position()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course the position() does not work. But how can I get the previous result? (The alphabet in the list is used for simplicity. In the real list there is no implied logic of ABC so one really has to use something like preceding-sibling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know about preceding sibling then I am not sure why you haven't used it: `key('letter-lookup', ., $alphabet)/preceding-sibling::row[1]/letter`.

Comment: sometimes one is to concerned with the big picture one loses the eye for the detail! this is what happened to me